# Passing an integer from one .java class used within an IF statement to another .java class using an Intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent, if-statement, android-activity

I am new to Android and I am trying to pass an integer value from one .java class to another using an Intent. The integer is declared within the first .java file and used within an IF statement to produce a score;

```
public class Diabetes_Question_1 extends Activity {

public int Total = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.diabetes_question_1);

    Button btnBack = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBack1);
    btnBack.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Diabetes_Question_1.this, Diabetes_Question_2.class));

        }
    });

    final RadioButton rb1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.btnDQ1Radio1);
    final RadioButton rb2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.btnDQ1Radio2);
    final RadioButton rb3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.btnDQ1Radio3);
    Button btnNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNext1);
    btnNext.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(rb1.isChecked()==true) {
                Total = 1;
            } else if (rb2.isChecked()==true) {
                Total = 2;
            } else if (rb3.isChecked()==true) {
                Total = 3;
            } else {
                Total = 4;
            }

            Toast.makeText(Diabetes_Question_1.this, String.valueOf(Total), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Intent i = new Intent(Diabetes_Question_1.this, Diabetes_Question_3.class);
            i.putExtra("totalScore", Total);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}
}
```

Once this score has been produced I would like to pass it onto another .java class so the score can be added to based on the next IF statement;

```
public class Diabetes_Question_3 extends Activity {

Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
int Total3 = extras.getInt("totalScore");

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.diabetes_question_3);

    Button btnBack = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBack2);
    btnBack.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Diabetes_Question_3.this, Diabetes_Question_1.class));

        }
    });

    final RadioButton rb1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.btnDQ3Radio1);
    final RadioButton rb2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.btnDQ3Radio2);
    final RadioButton rb3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.btnDQ3Radio3);
    Button btnNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNext3);
    btnNext.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Diabetes_Question_3.this, Diabetes_Question_4.class));

            if(rb1.isChecked()==true) {
                Total3 = + 1;
            } else if (rb2.isChecked()==true) {
                Total3 = + 1;
            } else if (rb3.isChecked()==true) {
                Total3 = + 1;
            } else {
                Total3 = + 1;
            }

            Toast.makeText(Diabetes_Question_3.this, String.valueOf(Total3), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
}
}
```

I know the IF statement works as I have a toast to show this. However moving onto the next .java class is where the problem is and I am struggling to improve the code.

I am giving the following error message;

FATAL EXCEPTION: Main java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo {PACKAGE NAME} java.lang.NullPointerExcpetion

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this.

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
int Total3 = extras.getInt("totalScore");
```

inside the onCreate method of Diabetes_Question_3 activity.

**You should follow the naming convention of Java.**

```
int total3 = 0; //Instance variable.

Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.diabetes_question_3);

    .........
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    total3 = extras.getInt("totalScore");
```

Comment: Thank you for a quick response. The variable Total3 isn't being recognised within the .java class. Any ideas why?

Comment: @DWhitman15 Checked once again my edited answer declare that variable instance

Comment: I can progress to the next activity but the integer value Total hasn't been brought over nor increased. Seems that total3 resets the Total integer. Any ideas why this is?

Comment: I defined the Total variable within the previous activity. I thought the Intent brings the Total variable from the previous activity to the new activity so it can be added to?

Comment: @DWhitman15 What you getting value in total in second activity

Comment: So within the first activity the 'public int Total' is being defined as a score value (1, 2, 3 or 4). I am trying to move this defined score to the second activity; so it should be either one of the score values, and then added to based on the score value defined within the second activity. For instance; activity 1 the score value is 4, in activity 2 the score is increased to 5, and so on

Comment: @DWhitman15 Have you debug the application what values are you getting in second activity.

Comment: When I run the application and select a radio button I am produced what ever score value is assigned to that button not the increased number

Comment: @DWhitman15 If you follow my answer then change the variable name of button listner to that. `total3 ` and put the `startActivity(new Intent(Diabetes_Question_3.this, Diabetes_Question_4.class));` at the end of button listner. after Toast.

Comment: The moving to the next activity works perfectly, however I can't see if the Total score value (my main value) has increased as the toast on activity Diabetes_Question_3 just shows the total3 value which is always 1 as I am always adding 1 to Total

Comment: @DWhitman15 If you set the `total3 = extras.getInt("totalScore");` total3 here then use `total3 = + 1;` and `Toast.makeText(Diabetes_Question_3.this, String.valueOf(total3), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`